# I'm getting internal error 500 from my web

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

When I enter from my computer I can see the web correctly but when I try to enter from a mobile phone with android I get internal error 500. In fact, if you use [PageSpeed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

You'll be able to see this error.

I had several things in my .htaccess and I removed most of it and I only have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The site is www.blbalba.com. If you enter, you'll get a header location to www.blbalba.com/

Please let me know if you have any idea about what it could be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a server error - look in the server error log for any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be the `User-Agent` Chrome on Android is sending. Try the following curl request:

```
#Desktop Chrome Linux version 35.0.1916.114
#Returns HTTP status 200

curl 'http://www.blablabla.com/negocio' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36' \
--compressed
```

vs this one:

```
#Mobile Chrome Android version 35.0.1916.138
#Returns HTTP status 500 

curl 'http://www.blablabla.com/negocio' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 5 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.138 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
--compressed
```

The only difference between these two is the `User-Agent`.

See if your server is doing some work with the the User-Agent, and if so temporarily disable that, until you can upgrade your framework User-Agent detection, or patch the bug yourself.

Comment: I only have allow to change htaccess, I asked my hosting provider but they didn't know if they are doing something with user-agent. Is there any way to disable user-agent detection from .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: You dont control any of the backend code? You're not using php etc?

Comment: Ok so maybe check if your PHP code is accessing User-Agent in some way. Are you using a PHP framework by any chance? (Zend, Laravel, Slim etc.)

Comment: I don't use any framework and I don't access user-agent in anywhere.

Comment: I've installed wordpress on www.cuponalfa.com/blog in order to test... I suppose the htaccess that uses wordpress is correct but it happens the same, it isn't possible to see the blog from a mobile device. I've raisen a ticket and my provider is working on it.

Comment: Your .htaccess file is fine - would be good if you could get logs so we could see the exact error - HTTP 500 always means check your logs for more detailed information

Comment: There was something wrong on the server side and it's already fixed... they use a service called dattamobile and it's specific for mobile device and they disabled that service and my site started to work.... thanks so much